# Google Spreadsheets: how to import several pages?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've seen that there are some functions which allow you to import data into a google spreadsheet, like importHTML or importXML.

However, I don't manage to see how I could do if the data I am trying to import is spread across multiple pages, for example:

http://fanpagelist.com/category/top_users/view/list/sort/fans/page1
http://fanpagelist.com/category/top_users/view/list/sort/fans/page2
http://fanpagelist.com/category/top_users/view/list/sort/fans/page3

Any idea if it'd be possible to collect the results of a group of pages in a single google spreadsheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the builtin functions. Write an apps script and call urlFetch in a loop. Use spreadsheetApp to write the rows. Create a menu to invoke the script.